# Platform.RunLater like behaviour thread imeplementation based on JFXAT PlatformImpl to throw work at

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

So I decided to create my own   **Platform**,**PlatformImpl** *like implementation* to basically avoid intensive synchronization and synchronization problems at places where it should not be needed, my requirement is that I have a thread that I can throw work at  from JFXAT or other threads that I happen to be in. What I do now its creating thread from JFXAT when user has to for instance delete something from database on user input and then reflect this change in model etc since I dont want my communication to happen on JFXAT.

**Am I going little overboard with this? I like how JavaFX and swing has dedicated thread that you just throw work at and you dont have to expect any problems, things I create threads for really would need just some one thread where queue of jobs would be constantly executed as needed. Preferably FIFO structure emebeded within**.

**Is there already elegant solution for this ? Some API in standard java that I don't know about?**
I don't really have place to reffer to when I want to execute my application logic  thats my problem , I create a lot of threads or execute on JFXAT (light weight tasks nothing heavy/bud might change) and I'm in constant worry about synchronization and forced to use thread safe collections, I know this is pretty dumb question bud i tend to overcomplicate things in my design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executors seem to fit your needs.

More precisely you describe the kind of `ExecutorService` that [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) returns.

Example:

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void runLater(Runnable runnable) {
    executor.execute(runnable);
}
```

Comment: This is actually pretty simple i totally forgot about executors i have read about them before even used one bud didnt came to my mind to actually use it for this purpose, thank you gonna try to implement it around this :)

Comment: Sort-of-relatedly, note that you can abstract the idea of `Platform.runLater()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` as an `Executor` (which, in the end, is just something that executes `Runnable`s). I.e. you can do `Executor exec = Platform::runLater;` or `Executor exec = SwingUtilities::invokeLater;`. This allows the possibility of creating "UI-agnostic" controllers in which client code (or a DI framework) can specify the UI update mechanism. [An example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79154/generic-gui-background-task-runner-java-8)